# Different resolutions HDMI-1/HDMI-2 in Screen Layout Editor

Tags: display, pi-4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (2GB) connected to 2 displays of resolution 3840x600 each (58:9 aspect ratio), running the latest version of Buster. To have the display in correct resolution, I have edited the `config.txt` file with the following values:

```
...
framebuffer_width=3840
framebuffer_height=600
...
hdmi_cvt=3840 600 30
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2

gpu_mem=256
...
```

On booting the Pi, both screens come alive with the HDMI-1 showing the RPi logo on top left, and HDMI-2 showing the splash screen. Once the Desktop is loaded, HDMI-1 works absolutely fine with the resolution 3840x600. However, HDMI-2 does not respect this resolution.

When trying to change the resolutions through the Screen Layout Editor, HDMI-1 shows all 4K options, along with my custom resolution of 3840x600. However, HDMI-2 only allows FullHD resolutions and below.

Screen Layout Editor :
[image]
*(captured with `PrtScr`, screenshot size is 3840x900!!)*

Resolution Options HDMI-1 :
[image]

Resolution Options HDMI-2 :
[image]
*(Selected 1920x300 to maintain aspect ratio)*

**EDID dump [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/br8s04meuhgke05/EDID_info.txt?dl=0)**

Is there any way I can get both displays to run at 3840x600?

Comment: Are both displays identical? Do they advertise the 3840x600 resolution via EDID?

Comment: Yes, `EDID:found unknown detail timing format: 3840x600p hfp:147 hs:393 hbp:540 vfp:3 vs:10 vbp:11 pixel clock:184 MHz`